# Pullback and Kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

We consider everything in the category of groups. It is known that monomorphisms are stable under pullback; that is, if 
$$\begin{array}
AA_1 & \stackrel{f_1}{\longrightarrow} & A_2 \\
\downarrow{h} & & \downarrow{h'} \\
B_1 & \stackrel{g_1}{\longrightarrow} & B_2  
\end{array}
$$ is a pullback, then $g_1$ being one-to-one implies that $f_1$ is also one-to-one. Now if we weaken the condition, suppose that the kernel of $g_1$ is known, what can we say about the kernel of $f_1$? More precisely, if there is a commutative diagram

$$\begin{array}
A &  & B_0 &  & A_1 &\stackrel{f_1}{\longrightarrow} & A_2\\
 & & \parallel & &\downarrow{h}& &\downarrow{h'}\\
0 & \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} &B_0 & \stackrel{g_0}{\longrightarrow} &B_1 & \stackrel{g_1}{\longrightarrow} & B_2  & \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & 0
\end{array}$$

where the last row is an exact sequence and $A_1$ is the pullback, can we complete an exact sequence in the first row? Or at least is there a natural map from $B_0$ to $A_1$ making the diagram commutative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a pullback diagram we always have $\ker(f_1)\cong\ker(g_1)$.

For, we have the inclusion $\ker(g_1)\to B_1$ and the trivial map $\ker(g_1)\to A_2$. By the universal property of the pullback, we obtain a unique map $\ker(g_1)\to A_1$, whose image is then contained in $\ker(f_1)$. This gives the required inverse to the induced map $\ker(f_1)\to\ker(g_1)$.

Answer (score 1):

There is an exact sequence
$0 \to \ker(f_1) \cap \ker(h) \to \ker(f_1) \to \ker(g_1) \to 0$. I doubt that more can be said.